# Query do Laravel retorna resultado "errado"

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tenho uma tabela chamada "tabela_precos", com a seguinte estrutura:

```
categoria_veiculo_id | valor | preco_min | preco_max | tipo_veiculo
22                     77,70   0           2500        carros  
22                     30,35   15000       20000       carros
```

Quando executo a seguinte query no phpmyadmin, o retorno é correto e só traz um resultado (**o registo com valor 30,35**):

```
select * from `tabela_precos` where `tipo_veiculo` = "carros" and `categoria_veiculo_id` = 22 and 15000 between preco_min and preco_max ;
```

mas quando executo isso no Laravel, ele me retorna os dois registros (mesmo usando `limit 1` ou `first()`, código:

```
$query = TabelaPreco::whereRaw('? between preco_min and preco_max', [$request->preco_fipe])
        ->where('categoria_veiculo_id', $request->categoria_veiculo_id)
        ->where('tipo_veiculo', $request->tipo_veiculo);
```

esses dados vêm de um formulário, e mesmo eu colocando os dados diretamente no código, os mesmos dois registros são retornados.

Já dei um `toSql()` e a query é exatamente a mesma que executei diretamente no phpmyadmin

Sei que isso é provavelmente algo muito bobo, mas não consegui entender porque isso acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de rodar a internet toda procurando isso, acabou que o erro era era que eu estava enviando os valores do `preco_fipe` como `string` e por isso gerou esse resultado "estranho", quando fiz a conversão pra `int` os resultados vieram certos

Comment: não entendi porque negativaram minha resposta, ninguém soube responder, é um detalhe sutil mas difícil de perceber...